# Instead of the contents of the HTML page, code is displayed

Tags: python, html, django

I am writing a site in Python, Django. After updating PyCharm, the HTML page in the browser displays not its contents, but the code! What can be done with this?

Here's how it displays in a browser:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>News Agent</title>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="https://www.cbsnews.com/live-updates/coronavirus-outbreak-death-toll-us-infections-latest-news-updates-2020-03-05/">hhjhj</a>

    <a href="https://www.cbsnews.com/news/flat-earth-climate-change-conspiracies-students-teachers-war-on-science-cbsn-originals/">hhjhj</a>

    <a href="https://www.cbsnews.com/news/mcconnell-slams-schumers-comments-on-supreme-court-justices-watch-live-stream-03-05-2020/">hhjhj</a>

    <a href="https://www.cbsnews.com/news/first-coronavirus-death-california-linked-grand-princess-cruise-ship-quarantine/">hhjhj</a>

    <a href="https://www.cbsnews.com/news/lori-vallow-update-extradited-idaho-charges-tylee-ryan-jj-missing/">hhjhj</a>

    <a href="https://www.cbsnews.com/news/james-paul-markowitz-border-patrol-waited-to-call-for-help-after-us-man-who-died-in-custody-showed-signs-distress/">hhjhj</a>

    <a href="https://www.cbsnews.com/news/bernie-sanders-says-joe-biden-should-be-winner-of-democratic-nomination-if-he-has-plurality-of-delegates/">hhjhj</a>

    <a href="https://www.cbsnews.com/news/mlks-son-asks-alabama-to-stop-looming-execution-of-nathaniel-woods/">hhjhj</a>

    <a href="https://www.cbsnews.com/news/stock-markets-down-coronavirus-hit/">hhjhj</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Code from the view:

```
def index(request):
    url = "https://www.cbsnews.com/"
    all_links = get_all_links(get_html(url))
    for link in all_links:
         html = get_html(link)

    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'all_links': all_links})
```

Comment: Post the code that should be rendering the HTML. Without knowing how it currently works no one will be able to tell you how to fix it

Comment: There it is: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>News Agent</title>
</head>
<body>



    <a href="#">hhjhj</a>

</body>
</html>

Comment: No.... Post the code that generates and renders that HTML to your web browser. What you just posted is valid HTML so should be shown by a browser. So clearly something is wrong with how it's being sent to the browser. Also please do not post code in the comments, the formatting gets messed up and it's hard to read, please edit your original post with the code.

Comment: I'm Sorry... done

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], or at least some of the relevant code.

Comment: @Ekzotika007 Please show the Python code from your view that produces this output.

Comment: @Matthias It's done

Comment: Okay it looks like you need to look into templates. What you have posted is just html, not a template. When you load plain html as your template its going to load as plain html. If you want to add your data to it you need to load it as a template which generates the html, with your data inside - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/

Comment: Also your `for` loop isnt doing anything. It loops and overwrites the `html` variable each time. And then you do nothing with the html variable.

Comment: It could be a mime type issue. I.e., something sends `text/plain` instead of `text/html` to the browser...